# Invalid values from cookies after explode/list()

Tags: php

```
setcookie("mnau", "1-445 1-51 1-3001");
$kosik = explode(" ", $_COOKIE["mnau"]);

foreach($kosik as $value) {
    list($item_ajdi, , $itemcount) = $value;
    echo $item_ajdi . " : " . $itemcount . ",";
}
```

Returns values 1 : 4, 1 : 5, 1 : 3, instead of 1 : 445 etc.

Comment: I think `$value` is a string type. You're selecting the first and the third element (so character). You might want to explode even further on `-`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Fabio's answer is the best, but if you want to keep you current code, you need to do what @Caramiriel recommends and explode `$value` on `-`, to make it an array before using it in `list()`.

```
setcookie("mnau", "1-445 1-51 1-3001");
$kosik = explode(" ", $_COOKIE["mnau"]);
foreach($kosik as $value) {
    $value = explode("-", $value);
    list($item_ajdi,$itemcount) = $value;
    echo $item_ajdi . " : " . $itemcount . ", ";
}
```

with output

```
1 : 445, 1 : 51, 1 : 3001,
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to loop in your exploded array and then replace `-` with `:`

```
setcookie("mnau", "1-445 1-51 1-3001");
//var_dump($_COOKIE);

$kosik = explode(" ", $_COOKIE["mnau"]);
foreach ($kosik as $value) {
    echo str_replace('-', ':', $value) . ', ';
}
```

This will output

```
1:445, 1:51, 1:3001,
```

Comment: I actually put the echo there just for simplification, the function itself uses the values separately, but that wouldn't be much use to others. However, thanks.